# How to finish this git rebase operation?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I cloned a remote repo, then branched a feature branch `mybranch` out of `master`. A few commits later, running `git status` I see:

```
On branch mybranch
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        model/ABC/
        model/XYZ/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

which is fine, as I don't care about `ABC` and `XYZ` binary directories.

Now, I want to rebase my branch on master to incorporate latest updates that were pushed by teammates. So, I checkout `master`, pull the latest changes, checkout `mybranch` again and do:

```
git rebase master
```

The rebase runs until a point where I get the following message:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Dirty index: cannot apply patches (dirty: blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C.3
blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C::Cached.3
blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Digest::CRC.3)
```

Checking the status at this point yields:

```
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'mybranch' on '4e4ad5a'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C.3
        deleted:    blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C::Cached.3
        deleted:    blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Digest::CRC.3

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

            model/ABC/
            model/XYZ/
```

Our project (and repo) is maintained in a mixed Linux-Windows environment. Apparently, the files indicated above are man files of the Perl package, that are not cloned correctly on the Windows environment (due to ugly filenames?)

**How can I conclude this rebase operation and overcome this stage of the process?**

UPDATE 1: If it matters, the local repo was cloned using a sparse checkout. The problematic files are part of a directory *not* on the local workspace.

UPDATE 2: Following @TriskalJM's answer, I committed the changes at that stage:

```
git commit -m "MY-COMMENT" .
```

and got this message:

```
error: Invalid path 'blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C.3'
error: Invalid path 'blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C::Cached.3'
error: Invalid path 'blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Digest::CRC.3'
[detached HEAD 12d77df] MY-COMMENT
 3 files changed, 12542 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C.3
 delete mode 100644 blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Convert::Binary::C::Cached.3
 delete mode 100644 blahblah/local_install/Perl/man/man3/Digest::CRC.3
```

Checking status shows that the `rebase` operation is not done yet, so using `--continue`, I get the following message:

```
sed: can't read blah/.git/rebase-apply/info: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to force the finish of this rebase?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to just merge the master?

Comment: Just a workflow we have here. Anyway, I tried merging `master` into `mybranch` and wasn't successful as well, probably due to same files.

Comment: What happens if you try `--skip` instead of `--continue`?

Comment: I tried reverting to the last commit before the rebase attempt but things only got south from there. At this point I decided not to waste more time on this, re-cloned the repo and started allover. However, on the old (problematic) repo I tried the `--skip` and I get a long list of warnings and conflicts.

Comment: I think you're going to have to consider the old (problematic) repo scorched earth.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you've hit upon one of the problems with using git cross-platform. The developers who added those files to the repo have committed a grievous sin because they've made it impossible to use the workflow as intended from a Windows machine.

You're going to have to commit the changes as-is (which will remove those man pages), and have them recommit those pages from a linux machine.

In addition, it sounds like you need to have a discussion as a team about how to mitigate this in the future.

Also, if you don't care about `model/ABC` and `model/XYZ` because they contain binaries, you should add those to a `.gitignore`.

Comment: I see, thanks. As usual, if there's anybody to go to the dark side of tools it will be me....

Comment: This one's not your fault. :)

Comment: @TriskaIJM - I updated the question following your answer, but it seem that the problem is not resolved yet. I will (temporarily) pull the "accespted" mark.

Comment: No worries. Complications abound!